# CSS iPad orientation issue

Tags: html, css, ipad, wicket

I was hoping someone could help. I was having an alignment problem with a responsive website I was building when altering the orientation.  So I used the following css to try to fix my web page. The odd thing is that it is having the effect of shrinking some other images elsewhere in the website so that they get progressively smaller each time I alter the orientation relative to the fixed width object next to them which stays the same size. The changing images in question have different css tags to the ones in the code below but have % sizes.  When I remove the CSS code below the strange behaviour stops.

The 4 objects in questions are divs connected to apache wickets. They sit in a page which is divided into 3 areas with tables (don't ask.) The other two areas have fixed width objects which are unaffected.

This unexpected thing happens on my iPad but not my android tablet. On the iPad it happens in both Safari and Chrome. I could probably fix it by giving fixed sizes to iPad objects in CSS, but I'd rather understand what's happening. Here's the CSS

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) 
#Button1 {
clear:left;
float:left;
width:380%;
padding-top:0%;
padding-bottom: 0%;
padding-left:20%;
min-width:220%;  }
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
#Value1 {
clear:left;
float:left;
padding-left:20%;
font-size: 520%;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal; 
color:#CF3;
}   
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
#Button2 {
clear:left;
float:left;
width:380%;
padding-top:5%;
min-width:220%;
padding-left:20%;
}   
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
.symbol {
font-size: 320%;
color: #FFF;
}   
}
```

Corresponding entries for portrait followed, so that there were options for portrait and browser mode. If anyone can explain this behaviour I'd be most interested and grateful. To re-iterate, images in another part of the site are affected when I change their orientation, and only on iPad. The images that are the target of this CSS are behaving exactly as they are supposed to, on all platforms.